# Pocketsphinx in python returns random words in keyword search

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

I copied a code from a website to listen to specific words in python using pocketsphinx.It although runs but never outputs the keyword as expected.This is my code:

```
import sys, os
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *
import pyaudio

# modeldir = "../../../model"
# datadir = "../../../test/data"

modeldir="C://Users//hp//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python35//Lib//site-packages//pocketsphinx//model//en-us"
dictdir="C://Users//hp//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python35//Lib//site-packages//pocketsphinx//model//cmudict-en-us.dict"
lmdir="C://Users//hp//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python35//Lib//site-packages//pocketsphinx//model//en-us.lm.bin"
# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', modeldir)
config.set_string('-lm', lmdir )
config.set_string('-dict', dictdir)
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'forward')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyword detected perform action and restart search
decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
         decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
         break
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
      #print(decoder.hyp().hypstr)
      if decoder.hyp().hypstr == 'forward':
        print ([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
        print ("Detected keyword, restarting search")
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```

Also when I use   `print(decoder.hyp().hypstr)`

It just outputs random words when i speak anything.For ex if i speak a word or line it outputs:

```
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the
the da
the head
the bed
the bedding
the heading of
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and
the bedding and well
the bedding and well
the bedding and well
the bedding and butler
the bedding and what lingus
the bedding and what lingus
the bedding and what lingus
the bedding and what lingus ha
the bedding and blessed are
the bedding and blessed are
the bedding and what lingus on
the bedding and what lingus want
the bedding and what lingus want
the bedding and what lingus want
the bedding and what lingus want
the bedding and what lingus want or
the bedding and what lingus want to talk
the bedding and what lingus current top
the bedding and what lingus want to talk
the bedding and what lingus want to talk
the bedding and what lingus want to talk
the bedding and what lingus want to talk
the bedding and what lingus want to talk to her
the bedding and what lingus want to talk to her
the bedding and what lingus want to talk to her
the bedding and what lingus want to talk to her
```

Please help me through it.I am just a newbie in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this line

```
  config.set_string('-lm', lmdir )
```

Keyphrase search and lm search are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.It really worked.I needed to ask you if there is a way to hear for more than 1 keyphrase or a sentence in pocketsphinx.Is that possible?

Comment: yes, you can add it with a keyword list.
On the config do: ```config.set_string('-kws', 'file_location')```. Then in that file have your keywords, one on each line, in this format: ```open /1e-1/```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I just want to clarify; your Pocketsphinx *is* working.

So, based on my experience using [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx), it is hardly the [most accurate](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-why-my-accuracy-is-poor) voice recognition tool you can use, but probably your best bet for an Offline solution. Pocketsphinx can only translate your words (audio) as best as its' [model](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/) prescribes. These models seem to still be a work in progress and much of it needs to be improved. There are a few things you can do to try increasing the accuracy of the recognition; such as [reducing noise](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-how-to-do-the-noise-reduction), and [tuning the recognition](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialtuning/), but that's outside the immediate scope of this question.

From what I understand in your code, you're looking for a specific keyword to be said (vocally, by the user) and have it recognized using pocketshinx's backend. This keyword seems to be "forward". You can read-up further on how to properly accomplish ["hot word listening"](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-how-to-implement-hot-word-listening).

You have the right idea, but the approach can be improved. Here is my "quick fix" version of your code:

```
import os
import pyaudio
import pocketsphinx as ps

modeldir = "C://Users//hp//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python35//Lib//site-packages//pocketsphinx//model//"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = ps.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'forward')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyword detected perform action and restart search
decoder = ps.Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()

while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
        break
    if decoder.hyp() is not None:
        print(decoder.hyp().hypstr)
        if 'forward' in decoder.hyp().hypstr:
            print([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
            print("Detected keyword, restarting search")
            decoder.end_utt()
            decoder.start_utt()
```

For any one `pocketsphinx.Decoder()` "session" (i.e. invoking the `.start_utt()` method, without subsequently calling `.ent_utt()`), the `decoder.hyp().hypstr` variable will effectively continue to add words to itself once it detects that the input audio stream had a "valid" translation/recognition from pocketsphinx's decoding.

You've used `if decoder.hyp().hypstr == 'forward':`. What this does is, it forces the whole string to be exactly "forward" for the code to enter that (I presume, desired... yes?) conditional codeblock. Since pocketshinx, by default, is not very accurate, it generally takes a few tries on most words to get it to actually register the correct word. For this reason, and since `decoder.hyp().hypstr` adds to itself (as previously explained), I've used the line `if 'forward' in decoder.hyp().hypstr:`. This looks for the desired keyword "forward" in the whole string. This way, it allows incorrect recognition until the keyword is found.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But this code is too of no help brother.It never recognises word 'forward' in speech and just prints out random word whenever i speak to it.Is there anything which i am missing in the model?

Comment: When i say 'forward' this is the output oh


oh
oh but
oh but
oh but
oh but
oh but oh
oh but oh

oh but oh
oh but oh
oh but oh
oh but oh
oh but oh
oh but oh

oh but oh apple or lawyer
oh but oh apple rick

oh but oh apple rid

oh but oh apple rick but
oh but oh apple rick before
oh but oh apple rick ball
oh but oh apple or lord butler
oh but oh apple rick ball

oh but oh apple rick bar were
oh but oh apple rick before our work

oh but oh apple rick before our word     <br> No sign of 'Detected keywo...' which means it never identifies the keyword.

Comment: All this means is pocketsphinx's "translation" is not very accurate with the data you're putting into it. Therefore, as I pointed out, you will have to try a few (many) times before pocketsphinx correctly recognizes your word. I understand how unsatisfactory this is. You will then need to look at **increasing the accuracy** of your recognition, and **properly** implementing "hot word listening". The links for these are provided in my original answer.